How can I change the default behaviour of curly-brackets-indentation alignment in LaTeX documents?
I have this LaTeX code:
\begin{xmpl}
  \xmplline
      {}
      {}
      \\
      \xmpllinebd
          {}
          {}
          {}
          \\[\xmplsep]
          \xmplline
              {}
              {}
              \\
              \xmpllinebd
                  {}
                  {}
                  {}
\end{xmpl}

I would like to change the default indentation for just the curly brackets so that they behave like round brackets:
\begin{xmpl}
  \xmplline
  {}
  {}
  \\
  \xmpllinebd
  {}
  {}
  {}
  \\[\xmplsep]
  \xmplline
  {}
  {}
  \\
  \xmpllinebd
  {}
  {}
  {}
\end{xmpl}

My boss forbids loading the AUCTeX package, so I am looking for a solution that does not involve loading it entirely. However, I am allowed to use individual AUCTeX functions. For example, I can use texmathp because I only need to load the texmathp.el file.
How can I change the default behaviour of curly-brackets-indentation alignment in LaTeX documents?

Set the variable tex-indent-arg to 0, either globally or in a file variable section at the bottom of the file:
...
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: LaTeX
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% tex-indent-arg: 0
%%% End:

That "works" to the extent that, given the input you provide, TAB on each line starting from the top, or M-x indent-region on the whole thing, will produce the output you desire. But bear in mind that there might be unwanted consequences in other situations.

[How would you come up with the above answer? The following is an attempt at "teaching you how to fish": I describe what I did to come up with the answer, given that I didn't know how to solve the problem beforehand.]
If you manually change the indentation of the first brace pair to what you want, and then use TAB on subsequent lines, then it looks like this:
\begin{document}
\begin{xmpl}
  \xmplline
  {}
  {}
  \\
  \xmpllinebd
      {}
...

IOW, subsequent brace pairs (and macros) will align correctly if you can get the alignment of the first brace pair the way you want it.
To find out who does the alignment, use describe-key (C-h k) in your LaTeX buffer to find out what function the TAB key runs: you'll find out that TAB runs indent-for-tab-command and the doc string (C-h f indent-for-tab-command) tells you that The function called to actually indent the line or insert a tab is given by the variable ‘indent-line-function’.
So we look at the doc string of the variable (C-h v indent-line-function - in the LaTeX buffer, since the value of the variable may be buffer-local) and it tells us that the value is latex-indent. Get the doc-string of the function (C-h f latex-indent) and click on the file link to get the source code of the function in another buffer:
latex-indent is a native-comp-function in ‘tex-mode.el’.
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ this will be a link that you can click on
...

[For the rest of this lesson, there are some prerequisites: you will need to know how to use Edebug and the only way to learn that is practice, practice, practice. You will also need an ability to read Lisp code which also comes with practice, perhaps following along in The Emacs Lisp Intro book. That will obviously take time and effort, but "there is no royal road to Geometry" - or to Emacs Lisp for that matter.]
Then instrument the function for edebug with C-u C-M-x. Now you can go back to your LaTeX buffer (restored to its initial indented state) and press TAB on the line with the first pair of braces. That will call latex-indent which is now instrumented for edebug, so execution will stop at the beginning of the function and you can step through it using SPACE. Go slowly and look at the result of each function evaluation in the echo area before pressing SPACE to go to the next one.
You will soon come to the following code:
...
       (let ((indent
         (save-excursion
           (beginning-of-line)
>          (latex-find-indent))))
...

and when you press SPACE on that line to evaluate the function call (latex-find-indent), the result will be 6. Guessing at that point that latex-find-indent is the relevant function, we can either continue (c) or quit (q) the debugging session: we want to go into latex-find-indent, so we are going to do the whole thing again, but now step into latex-indent to find out what it's doing.
So press TAB on the first pair of braces again and SPACE quickly to the (latex-find-indent) line, but stop when the cursor is on the opening parenthesis. [1] Then press i to step into the function and continue with SPACE to see what it's doing. You might want to read the code of latex-find-indent(even if you don't understand what it is doing) to get the "lay of the land", so to speak - the comments might help: they serve as signposts to help you orient yourself properly.
I did not follow all the wrinkles in the code, but stepping through it quickly brought me to the last part of the code, where the function is treating the arguments of LaTeX macros (the comment is telling...) In particular, this code:
           (if (< (line-end-position)
              (save-excursion (forward-comment (point-max))
                      (point)))
           ;; we're indenting the first argument.
           (min (current-column) (+ tex-indent-arg col))   ;<<<<<<<<<
         (skip-syntax-forward " ")
         (current-column))

where col is the indentation of the previous line (i.e. 2) and tex-indent-arg is a variable whose value is 4. [2] That explains the result 6 that we got in the previous run and also suggests that the way to get the braces to align with the macro is to set tex-indent-arg to 0. [3] Setting it up with a file-local variable as shown above and trying it out confirmed that it indeed does what you want in this case.

Footnotes:
[1] If you want to reach a point quickly, then you can set a breakpoint at that point - see the link above. When execution has stopped at the beginning of the function, you can use g to continue until the breakpoint is hit.
[2] While using edebug, when you are stopped at some point in the code, you can evaluate Lisp expressions (in particular, variables), by pressing e and then typing the expression in the minibuffer, e.g. type e and then type col in the minibuffer to see the value of the variable col at that point in the execution.
[3] Note that the variable tex-indent-arg is undocumented. That's probably worth a documentation bug report.

The solution with local variables is perfect so I can use it without affecting other working files. It works perfectly.
